# How to make sure the parent process executes scanf() before the child does?

Tags: c, process, fork, scanf

I'm writing a program that accepts two integer values from the user as input, X and Y (it's for an assignment).

The tricky part is that the program has to create a parent and child, where the parent process will read X and the child process will read Y (using `scanf`).

The expected output of the program is the following:

```
From parent 2255: child with PID 2256 is created 
From parent 2255: Reading X from the user
>> 99
>> X in parent is 99
From child: Reading Y from the user
>> 88
>> Y in child is 88
```

The issue I'm having is that the child executes automatically, and doesn't wait until input is received in the parent.

My professor gave a hint that we can use sleep() at the beginning of child process to solve this problem, but I'm not having any luck.

My sample code (which isn't working):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>  // pid_t
#include <unistd.h>     // NULL, fork()
#include <errno.h>      // errno

int main(void){

    // Initializing variables
    int X = 0, Y = 0;

    // Fork 
    pid_t pid;          
    pid = fork();

    // ERROR
    if (pid < 0){
        // error handling
    }
    // PARENT
    else if (pid > 0){

        // Read X
        printf("From parent %d: Reading X from the user\n>> ", pid);
        scanf(" %d", &X);
        printf("X in parent is %d\n", X);

        // Some other code afterwards
    }
    // CHILD
    else {

        // Read Y
        printf("From child: Reading Y from the user\n>> ");
        scanf(" %d", &Y);
        printf("Y in child is %d\n", Y);

        // Some other code afterwards
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: One method of Synchronizing access to resources by multiple processes can be done with a semaphore.  Another could be creating a pipe between parent and child... the child waits for a "go ahead" message on the pipe, which is sent by the parent when its scanf has completed.

Comment: Putting a call to sleep at the beginning of the child process is sloppy coding, but if that's what your professor wants, why don't you do it?

Comment: @rici When I add `sleep(5)` at the start of the child process, the program only executes the parent's code and exits, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use signals to do interprocess synchronization

Comment: @alex: that is because you are not wait()ing for the child to finish, which you always need to do, even if you use proper synchronization functions like everyone else is telling you. Btw, 5 seconds is way too much. A second is plenty. 'man wait` should get you going.

Comment: @rici I need to run some more code in the child afterwards (the question involves creating a pipe and sharing the input between the parent and the child), so I can't wait until the child terminates unfortunately. Thanks though, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @alex: the parent always had to wsit for the child. It's a rule. Otherwise you create zombies. And if the parent waits for the child before the parent exits, the exit of the parent won't prematurely murder the child

Answer (score 0):

parent can wait for the child to finish, something along the following lines

```
    printf("X in parent is %d\n", X);

    int status = 0;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    // Some other code afterwards
```

The side effect is that // some other code afterwards will only be executed after child has exited.

If synchronization is required between the two process for reading X & Y and then do computation then consider using conditional variable (wait/signal). Something like parent waits on a condition that's set by child so that parent can proceed further. The waitpid still might be a good idea unless you do not have a concern about creating a zombie process (that is the parent exits without reaping its child's status) or are setting the SIGCHLD appropriately.